# only first if statement run, and unless it comes back true it will not continue. new to code

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, python-3.11

```
import random

user_wins = 0
computer_wins = 0

options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

while True:
    user_input = input("Type Rock/Paper/Scissors or Q to quit: ")
    if user_input == "q":
        break
    
    if user_input not in [options]:
        continue
        
    random_number = random.randint(0, 2)
    # rock: 0, paper: 1, scissors: 2
    computer_pick = options[random_number]
    print("computer picked", computer_pick + ".")

    if user_input == "rock" and computer_pick == "scissors":
        print("You won!")
        user_wins += 1
        
    elif user_input == "scissors" and computer_pick == "paper":
        print("You won!")
        user_wins += 1
        
    elif user_input == "paper" and computer_pick == "rock":
        print("You won!")
        user_wins += 1
    
    else:
        print("You lost!")
        computer_wins += 1

print("You won", user_wins, "times.")
print("The cpu won", computer_wins, "times.")
print("Goodbye!")
```

I'm sorry if im not using this site the correct way but I've been following along with Tech With Tim on youtube trying to write 5 mini python games to just practice. I expect if i put q it will break, but now that i'm typing this i'm realizing that if it were to break i shouldn't get the print statements on line 37,38, and 39. either way, when i input rock , paper, or scissors it comes back as "Type Rock/Paper/Scissors or Q to quit:". I'm having a hard time understanding why my code doesnt work, while Tim has the exact same code, line for line, and his works fine. Any and all help would be appreciated.. even if its directing me to slow my roll

Answer (score 0):

`if user_input not in [options]` isn't correct. `[options]` is a list containing one element: all of `options`. A string can never be all of `options`, so `user_input not in [options]` will always be true.

You want

```
if user_input not in options:
```

Comment: that makes sense for sure i had went back and tried to forego 'options' and use '["rock", "paper", "scissors"]' and forgot to get rid of them, but even when i change 'if user_input not in [options]' to 'if user_input not in options:' it still does the same thing. again i sincerely apologize if i'm not using this site correctly. edit --no idea how to markup to make it look like code in comments btw

Comment: @thebodytalk You also have issues with capitalization. `options` has capital-case strings, but then you do checks like `user_input == "rock" ` later with lowercase letters. If the user enters lowercase strings, the string won't be in options. If they enter capital-case string, it will be in `options`, but will never compare as equal later. `"Rock" != "rock"`. Also, to format code in comments, surround the code in backticks.

Comment: I want to say I'm embarrassed but honestly this small victory feels so good. It was the capitalization that got me and now I have it running. Thank you so much for taking the time, I truly appreciate it.